# How to set callBack URL in @anywhere twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-anywhere

I am using @anywhere twitter API and I want to post a tweet using tweet box.  I have done following steps:

I registered app and Consumer Key is as following. I left callback URL to empty.

1. I have set Call Back URL while registering App is blank
2. Consumer Key: 94zA1u34whtdXz91Kjymgw

   ```
   <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=94zA1u34whtdXz91Kjymgw&v=1" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js">
   </script>
   ```

and I am creating tweet box as following,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#shareonTwitter').click(function (e) {
           alert('hello1234567');
           twttr.anywhere.config({ callbackURL: "http://localhost:1461/ShareonTwitter.html" });
           twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
               T("#tbox").tweetBox({
                   height: 100,
                   width: 400,
                   defaultContent: "Hi how r u ?"
               });
           });
       });
   });
```

I am getting error after authentication Technical Problem. I am not able to tweet. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could be because of the markup or how the example is setup. Could you try to reproduce it on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I read myself a little into the documentation and I found the following:

> Please note: The call to twttr.anywhere.config() must precede the call
>   to twttr.anywhere(). And the callback URL must match both the
>   subdomain and domain of the web application utilizing @Anywhere.
>
> **Authorizing Additional Domains for @Anywhere**
>
> Some implementors may want their @Anywhere API Key to function across
>   multiple domains or subdomains. By default, @Anywhere will only work
>   with the domain specified in the "Callback URL" field of the
>   application record.
>
> To authorize additional domains for @Anywhere, begin by going to your
>   applications, and clicking on the @Anywhere application name you want
>   to configure. Now select Manage Domains from the right-hand sidebar.
>
> You can enter up to 5 additional domains here, by typing a domain name
>   you want to authorize in the field provided and clicking Authorize. Be
>   sure and only authorize domains that you trust.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#custom-callback

Any callback url must be in your authored domains. This means that you must had localhost in your domain list. Since you can't register localhost with you api/consumer key you can't do this on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use localhost addresses as callback URLs. Try the code after hosting it on a web server somewhere.